# How do I access an ArrayList with user input using 2 classes?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, getter-setter

I have an object class called "Services" as shown below...

```
public class Services {

private ArrayList<Double> costDATA = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> costWLAN = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> costUTILITY = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> serviceNames = new ArrayList<>();
private double solution;
private double battery;

public void addServiceName(String services) {
    this.serviceNames.add(services);
}

public void addDimensions(String services) {
    this.dimensions.add(services);
}

public int getDimensionSize(){
    return dimensions.size();
}

public void addDataCost(double dataCost){
    costDATA.add(dataCost);
}

public void addWlanCost(double wlanCost){
    costWLAN.add(wlanCost);
}

public void addUtilityCost(double utilityCost){
    costUTILITY.add(utilityCost);
}

public void setSolution(double solution){
    this.solution = solution;
}

public double getSolution(){
    return solution;
}

public void setBattery(double battery){
    this.battery = battery;
}

public double getBattery() {
    return battery;
}


public ArrayList<Double> getCostDATA() {
    return costDATA;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getCostWLAN() {
    return costWLAN;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getCostUTILITY() {
    return costUTILITY;
}

public ArrayList<String> getServiceNames() {
    return serviceNames;
}
}
```

I use this class to store user input data from the MainActivity of my UI. Here is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//declare variables
private EditText name;
private EditText data;
private EditText wlan;
private EditText utility;
private Button addservice;
ListView lv;
ListView lv2;
ListView lv3;
ListView lv4;

Services services = new Services();
public ArrayList<String> servicenames;
public ArrayList<String> dimensions;
private ArrayAdapter<String> namesAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<Double> dataAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<Double> wlanAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<Double> utilityAdapter;
private ArrayList<Double> costDATA;
private ArrayList<Double> costWLAN;
private ArrayList<Double> costUTILITY;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //map the components to the variables
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.servicename);
    data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
    wlan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wlan);
    utility = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.utility);
    addservice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addservice);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv2);
    lv3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv3);
    lv4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv4);

    //create arraylists for each component
    servicenames =  services.getServiceNames();
    costDATA = services.getCostDATA();
    costWLAN = services.getCostWLAN();
    costUTILITY = services.getCostUTILITY();

    //create adapters to pass on the arraylist
    namesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, servicenames);
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costDATA);
    wlanAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costWLAN);
    utilityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costUTILITY);

    //display each arraylist in the listviews
    lv.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
    lv2.setAdapter(wlanAdapter);
    lv3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    lv4.setAdapter(utilityAdapter);
    services.addDimensions("DATA");
    services.addDimensions("WLAN");
    onClickBtn();
}

public void onClickBtn() { //when user clicks button, the user input is added to the listview, and cleared for the next service

    addservice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String namesOfService = name.getText().toString(); //user input for service names
            String costOfData = data.getText().toString(); //user input for data costs
            String costOfWLAN = wlan.getText().toString(); //user input for wlan costs
            String costOfUtility = utility.getText().toString(); //user input for utility costs
            double doubleWLAN = Double.parseDouble(costOfWLAN); //convert user input into double
            double doubleData = Double.parseDouble(costOfData);
            double doubleUtility = Double.parseDouble(costOfUtility);
            //costDATA.add(doubleData); //add the double costs to each resource arraylist
            //costWLAN.add(doubleWLAN);
            //costUTILITY.add(doubleUtility);

            services.addDataCost(doubleData);
            services.addWlanCost(doubleWLAN);
            services.addUtilityCost(doubleUtility);
            services.addDimensions(namesOfService);
            services.addServiceName(namesOfService);


            namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            wlanAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            utilityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            name.setText(""); //empty the edit text fields when button is clicked
            wlan.setText("");
            data.setText("");
            utility.setText("");
        }
    });

}

public void nextButton(View view) //next button, onto the next activity
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ParticleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now my mainActivity works fine, the UI displays the user input costs and service names just the way I need it to. After this is done, the user then goes to an activity called "ParticleActivity" which then executes two other java classes called "CustomUseCase" and "CustomService". In my "CustomUseCase" class, I always get nullpointerexception and it states that my arrayLists are empty. What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to access the arraylist from the services object as that is where I thought the values will be stored?

```
public class CustomServiceSelection implements Goodness {

Services services;
private ArrayList<Double> costData = services.getCostDATA();
private ArrayList<Double> costWlan = services.getCostWLAN();
private ArrayList<Double> costUtilities = services.getCostUTILITY();
private double batteryCost = services.getBattery();

public CustomServiceSelection(double costOfBattery, ArrayList<Double> costOfData, ArrayList<Double> costOfWlan,
                              ArrayList<Double> costOfUtilities) {

    if (costUtilities == null || costUtilities.size() < 1 || costData.size() < 1 || costWlan.size() < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please add atleast 1 cost to Data, WLAN and Utility");
    }
    if (batteryCost < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Please enter a battery cost more than 1");
    }

    this.batteryCost = costOfBattery;
    this.costData = costOfData;
    this.costWlan = costOfWlan;
    this.costUtilities = costOfUtilities;
}
```

Comment: You're missing ParticleActivity in the question

Answer (score 1):

You get a nullpointerexception because you are trying to immediately access an unassigned variable

```
Services services; // null 

// These are all null references 
private ArrayList<Double> costData =  services.getCostDATA();
private ArrayList<Double> costWlan = services.getCostWLAN();
private ArrayList<Double> costUtilities = services.getCostUTILITY();
private double batteryCost = services.getBattery();
```

You need to pass some initialized instance of the Services class into a constructor of `CustomServiceSelection`, **then** initialize the lists and other things

Comment: thanks for this, this makes sense! so once the user enters costs for each arraylist in the MainActivity, how do I access it using a constructor? Sorry im still a noobie, if you could show an example thatll be awesome

Comment: For example... `new CustomServiceSelection(services)`

Comment: Maybe do some Java tutorials before diving into Android?

Comment: i completed the headfirst java book before i started, theres still some things I am trying to get my head around. Would it be possible to pass the instance of the Service object in MainActivity as a static instance which I access in CustomServiceSelection? Because new CustomServiceSelection(services) won't work as the parameters for that class is the arraylists costData, costWlan, costUtility and Battery

Comment: You get each of those lists from one Services object, so pass in that object, not each individual list. It will work if you wrote a new constructor (you can have multiple)

Comment: Okay I get that, so in my service class, I can make a constructor called public Service(some parameter)?? Unless this constructor was static, how would you access it ? Can you show me an example of a constructor I could make in services, have an object of Services in MainActivity and then call it in CustomUseCase? Sorry for the questions, I get what you're trying to say but I can't seem to access soemthing without setting it static.

Comment: You can, but that is not what I meant, nor will that help with what you are asking. `CustomServiceSelection` needs a separate constructor, not the Services class

Comment: I don't know what you have as static, but it probably isn't needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143043/discussion-between-az-islam-and-cricket-007).